# hello i have a problem importing a TXT file to a Text view in Android Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, text-files

hello I have a problem importing a TXT file to a Text view in Android Kotlin

I have gotten the permissions for the address of the file but I don't know how to read it and put it in the text view

i make a video to show you https://youtu.be/w2YaicpQUYM

the file I choose is in Download / sample.txt

reslutado cotent://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fsample.txt

```
lateinit var filepath : Uri        
button1.setOnClickListener {
            permisos()
        }
    

private fun permisos() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Toast.makeText(this, "permisos concedidos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        txtchoser()
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1000)
        Toast.makeText(this, "sin permisos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun txtchoser() {
    var intent = Intent()
    intent.setType("text/*")
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"selecciona el archivo"),1000)
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode==1000 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data !=null){
        filepath =data.data!!
        text1.setText("$filepath")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Datos subidos correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this file stored? Is it in your Android Studio project somewhere? Or is it somehow available directly on the device?

Comment: Si in somehow available directly  "download" folder sample.txt

Comment: Now you can see in te vídeo youtu.be/w2YaicpQUYM how it works and where is the file stored

Comment: And what is the problem you are trying to solve here? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: If you see the video https://youtu.be/w2YaicpQUYM  you will notice that I only get the path of the file, but not the data, but neglect that I can already read the data from the file, next step put data from a table to a database firestore firebase, ahh and the code forgot it Source with the solution is already in the following link https://mega.nz/folder/zwxQTKKR#buc04uDmw54cyXvW11l9ng file "kotlin txt intent read" I have not had time to put and explain the solution, maybe I will upload it later as a video to youtube, it will be like a vitacora.(. registration ) ,  good good bye